# What is equivalent of @XmlElements in Simple?

Tags: jaxb, annotations, simple-framework

What to replace JAXB annotation `@XmlElements` in Simple XML framework with?

```
@XmlElements({ 
    @XmlElement(name = "distance", type = DistanceCheck.class), 
    @XmlElement(name = "pattern", type = PatternCheck.class), 
    @XmlElement(name = "compare", type = ComparisonCheck.class),
    @XmlElement(name = "check", type = CustomCheck.class), 
    @XmlElement(name = "unique", type = UniquenessCheck.class) 
 })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent is:

```
@ElementUnion({
    @Element(name="distance", type=DistanceCheck.class),
    @Element(name="pattern", type=PatternCheck.class),
    @Element(name="compare", type=ComparisonCheck.class),
    @Element(name="check", type=CustomCheck.class),
    @Element(name="unique", type=UniquenessCheck.class)
})
```